# Sqlite3 doesnt save data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlite3-python

Hello I am trying to create api using flask but i am facing issue where sqlite is not saving data. here is the code below:

```
def data_insert(link):
    try:
        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO ping(links) VALUES ('{link}');")
        conn.commit()
        return "sucess"
    except sqlite3.DatabaseError as e:
        print("AN ERROR HAS OCCURED")
        print(chalk.red(e))
        return "an internal error has occured."
def get_links():
    try:
        links = c.fetchall()
        print(f"links:{links}")
        return links
    except sqlite3.DatabaseError or sqlite3.DataError as e:
        print(chalk.red(e))
        return "an internal error has occured."
```

and in flask.py:

```
@app.route("/submit-url")
def main():
    url = request.args.get("url")
    if url == None:
        return "please enter url",404
    else:
        output = db.data_insert(url)
        links = db.get_links()
        print(links)
        return output
```

What should have happened: terminal should show list of data
what actually happened: It returns empty list.

Comment: Please read this link carefully to prevent SQL injection attacks: [How to use placeholders to bind values in SQL queries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries)

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_links()` function is not making a query; it's iterating over whatever are the rows returned by the last use of `c`. (You really do *not* want to share a `c`ursor; get a new one for each query.)

Instead of just `links = c.fetchall()` with whatever you've last executed with `c`, you'll need a new cursor, and to actually query things:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT links FROM ping")
links = [r[0] for r in c.fetchall()]  # unpeel the row tuples to get just the single column
```

You should probably also get rid of the exception handling within those functions (and do it elsewhere); also, you'll want to use [`?` placeholders for those insertions](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries) so all in all:

```
def data_insert(link):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO ping(links) VALUES (?)", (link,))
    conn.commit()


def get_links():
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT links FROM ping")
    return [row[0] for row in c.fetchall()]
```